# drawable.xml to use images from SD Card

Tags: android, xml, external, drawable, sd-card

Is it possible to link image item in drawable.xml to SD Card resource?

The whole idea is that app is minimal in size and that on first launch I would download all the necessary resources from the web onto SD Card into app folder for later use.

I saw this in some Icon Packs where they download all the icons from web. And Icon packs use drawable.xml as the holder for all the icons, so it's not possible to programmatically use the images through code.

Any ideas on how this would be achievable?

edit:

here's the current drawable.xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item drawable="app_drawer" />
<item drawable="browser" />
<item drawable="sms" />

</resources>
```

ant it's use in appfilter.xml by Icon Pack:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- This scales the images to fit into your iconback -->
    <scale factor="1.0" />

    <!-- NOVA LAUNCHER STUFF -->
    <item component=":LAUNCHER_ACTION_APP_DRAWER" drawable="app_drawer" />
    <item component=":BROWSER" drawable="browser" />
    <item component=":SMS" drawable="sms" />

</resources>
```

So, what I would like is to have something like this in drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item drawable="/sdcard/appfolder/appdrawer" />
<item drawable="/sdcard/appfolder/browser" />
<item drawable="/sdcard/appfolder/sms" />

</resources>
```

The `<item drawable="file_name"/>` references to the proper image in /res/drawable/file_name.png inside the app structure.

Comment: How can you be sure the other Icon packs are using drawable.xml? Have given this a try? actually took a look at other apps approaches? Have you actually tried doing what your proposing? Give a try, show us that you've done something so we can help you move forward

Comment: In other words, give us some code to work on.

Comment: What do you mean with drawable.xml? Please give an example of such a file where you try to use images from file system. Show how you want it if it was possible. And tell where/how you want to use the .xml.